# RStudio: If a value in column A is less than x, return value in column B

Tags: r, rstudio

I am looking for a code to use in `RStudio` that will identify values from `column B` if the value in the same row in `column A` is less than `x`.

Specifically, if a value in column `N_LOG` is greater than 0.67, then I would like to know what the value is from the `ACTIVITY_ACTION_ID column`. The output can be a list or a table. Below is a picture of what my data looks like.

[Snip of my data, called eLINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHrly.png)

Thank you for your help.

UPDATE: I got an solution from a friend at work if anyone else is looking at this post in the future and needs the answer. Either of the lines below would work.

`head( with(eLINK_Sediment, eLINK_Sediment[0.67 < N_LOG,"ACTIVITY_ACTION_ID"])  )`

`head(  subset(eLINK_Sediment, 0.67 < N_LOG, ACTIVITY_ACTION_ID)  )`

So for example,

`head( with(filename, filename[value of interest < column to compare to value,"data from column you want"]) )`

Comment: try `df <- read.csv("Absolute_path_of_your_csv/your_csv.csv"); df_new <- df[df$N_LOG < 0.67, "ACTIVITY_ACTION_ID"]; head(df_new)`. Note that the issue is not related to 'rstudio' but `r` so in future you might need to tag your question with `r` and certainly [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) will help you get more responses.

Answer (score 1):

You could add another column to your data which based on an ifelse statement which lists the variable you are interested in listing if your criteria is met.

e.g.

```
data_$NEW_COLUMN_NAME <- ifelse( data_$N_LOG > 0.67, ACTIVITY_ACTION_ID, " ")
```

Ifelse is handy because it creates an if statement in 1 line of code and it can handle vectors, unlike normal if statements.